# Estimations and equivalences of binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients, random-graphs

I'm trying to understand a proof of a lemma in Erdos and Renyi's 1959 paper entitled "On random graphs I."  I'll write what they've written first and then describe the quantities and my confusion.  I'm stuck on a step in the proof in which the authors write:

"We obtain for $n \geq n_0,$ by using some elementary estimations,
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{s}\frac{\binom{\binom{n}{2}-s(n-s)}{N_c}}{\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{N_c}} \leq \frac{e^{(3-2c)s}}{s!} \quad \textrm{for $s \leq \frac{n}{2}$  and}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{s}\frac{\binom{\binom{n}{2}-s(n-s)}{N_c}}{\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{N_c}} \leq \frac{e^{(3-2c)(n-s)}}{(n-s)!} \quad \textrm{for $s\geq \frac{n}{2}$  so, since}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(\overline{E_M},n,N_c) \leq \sum_{M<s<n-\textstyle \frac{2N_c}{n}} \frac{\binom{n}{s} \binom{\binom{n}{2}-s(n-s)}{N_c}}{\binom{ \textstyle \binom{n}{2}}{N_c}} \textrm{,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(\overline{E_M},n,N_c) \leq \sum_{s>\frac{2N_c}{n}} \frac{e^{(3-2c)s}}{s!}+\sum_{s>M}\frac{e^{(3-2c)s}}{s!} \quad \textrm{for $n \geq n_0$."}
\end{equation}

There $n$ is the number of vertices in any of the graphs being considered for the probability $P(\overline{E_M},n,N_c)$ that a graph randomly chosen from all of the graphs on $n$ vertices with $N_c=\textrm{int}(\frac{1}{2}n\log(n)+cn)$ edges is a member of the class $\overline{E_M}$ of graphs which satisfy the property that, for a "large number" (I don't understand what this actually means) $M$ the largest connected component in those graphs has fewer than $n-M$ vertices.  $s$ is a quantity between $M$ and $n-\frac{2N_c}{2}$ introduced in the sum in the third equation above.  Unless I'm just about blind (which is certainly possible,) $n_0$ is not introduced in the paper, and I have no clue what it means.  My confusion is both about how the inequalities come about for the combinations (I've looked a little at Stirling's approximation and some identities on binomial coefficients and such things to no avail) and about how the bounds for the summations are transformed (why are $s \leq, \geq \frac{n}{2}$ chosen? What's $n_0$?)

If you've read this far and decided to help out and think that some more context might be necessary (or if you like the ideas and want to read the paper,) [here is a PDF](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-readings/erdos59random.pdf).
I'd really appreciate any insights, thanks very much for reading.

Comment: Hi, welcome to our community. This is a guess, and I hope someone will reply here soon, having more knowledge of this topic and this paper. $n_0$ may be simply a "big enough integer", whose specific value is not important. So the bottom line is that your inequalities hold "for all big enough $n$".

Comment: Hello, thanks for the welcome.  That helps, I'll start looking for approximations which are valid for large $n$.

Comment: I'm now seeing that similar questions have been asked previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96769/derivation-of-bound-on-expression-involving-binomial-coefficient-from-erd%c5%91s-and?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136040/elementary-bound-of-binomial-coefficient?rq=1), I'll look at these and try to edit the question accordingly.  StackExchange is awesome!

Comment: I've read through user940's answer to the second link in the previous comment and I'm trying to work through his demonstration using the appropriate lower bound $\frac{n}{log(n)}$ described by Maxime in an answer to that same question but I still don't see how the greater than case should be proven and I don't understand how the inequalities user940 introduces for each of the product versions of the combinations come about.

Comment: My ignorance is very limiting here; since user940 was looking to demonstrate that the written bound for $s$ was incorrect, I think they found a $\geq$ statement (showing that the quantity was $\geq$ the proposed lower bound) for the left hand side of the inequality written in the first equation in this question rather than a $\leq$ statement, so I don't think it's possible to follow their procedure and demonstrate that the inequality holds up.

Comment: I followed user940's procedure as best I could and arrived at the inequality $\frac{4}{3} \frac{\frac{-1}{2}n\log(n)+cn}{\frac{n}{\log(n)}} \log\Big(\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}-\frac{n}{\log(n)}(n-\frac{n}{\log(n)})+1}\Big) + \Big(\log(n)-\log(\log(n))\Big) \leq 3-2c$, for some choice of parameters $n=10000$ and $c=5$ the L.H.S. produces some number a little above $8$ which is certainly not $\leq 3-2*5 = -7$.